# issues with django-ckeditor : acts like regular TextField

Tags: django, ckeditor

I am trying to use the django-ckeditor in my models / forms. 
However, the RichTextField or CKEditorWidget seem to work like regular 
text field. This happens both on the admin site and in my own forms. 
I followed the installation guide as explained here : 
https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor 
I feel like there is some step I did wrong or something else I forgot 
to install, because there are no error message. 
Thanks for helping.

Comment: What version of Django are you using? Are you using the static files app? Are you using the devserver? Sounds like you aren't getting the static files served correctly. That app is still using MEDIA instead of STATC.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to attach the JS to your forms as discussed? Do you see any errors at the JS console?

Comment: I am using django version 1.3, locally.
I set the media and static files options in the setting.py.

Comment: I set the othe mendatory settings  : 
`CKEDITOR_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static_root/ckeditor/'
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'C:/MyApps/QHub/media/ck_uploads'`
I wrote a form  : 
`class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Media:
       js = ('ckeditor/ckeditor.js',)
    class Meta:
        model = Question`
Still - all looks like regular text filed.

Comment: Also... I noticed something strange. 
When I edit my templates and insert "manually" the ckeditor via the <script> The following happens : 
+ When I access the templates via the application server (django runserver) the ckeditor dosn't work.
+ When I just view my templates in a browser, the ckeditor does work!...

Comment: Hey, that sounds like your static file setup might be borked somehow. Please read the Django docs on that. That might give you some idea on how to proceed.